# Explicit example of Koszul complex

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, tensor-products

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $x$ and $y$ two elements in $R$. I want to construct the Koszul complex on $x$ and $y$. We start by the following two chain complexes

$$C_2=0\to C_1=R\xrightarrow{\ x\ } C_0= R\to C_{-1}=0$$
$$D_2=0\to D_1=R\xrightarrow{\ y\ } D_0= R\to D_{-1}=0$$
Now we construct the tensor product chain complex which we denote $CD:=C\otimes D$:
$$CD_2=C_1\otimes D_1=R\otimes R$$
$$CD_1=C_1\otimes D_0 \oplus C_0\otimes D_1 =R\otimes R \oplus R\otimes R $$
$$CD_0=C_0\otimes D_0=R\otimes R$$ and we get the chain complex
$$CD_3=0 \to CD_2=R \otimes R\xrightarrow{\ \partial_2\ } CD_1= R \otimes R \oplus  R \otimes R \xrightarrow{\ \partial_1\ } CD_0= R \otimes R \to CD_{-1} =0$$ We now compute $\partial_1$ and $\partial_2$:

$$\partial_2 (c_1\otimes d_1)=(xc_1)\otimes d_1-c_1\otimes (yd_1)$$ and 
$$\partial_1 (c_1\otimes d_0+c_0\otimes d_1)=(xc_1)\otimes d_0+c_0\otimes (yd_1).$$

> Now I want to move from here to express $\partial_1$ and $\partial_2$ in the way expressed in the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koszul_complex) (section Introduction). I don't understand the notation $R^2$ and the matrix expression of the differentials and where did the tensor product disappear from the final result.

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: $R^2 = R \oplus R$, which explains the matrices.  The tensor product disappeared because $R\otimes_R R\cong R$.

Comment: I still don't see how to get matrix expression for $\partial_1$ and $\partial_2$, can we say for example that 

$$\partial_2(c_1\otimes d_1)=\mathbf (x, -y) \begin{bmatrix} c_1\otimes d_1 & 0\\0 & c_1\otimes d_1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: and $$\partial_1 (c_1\otimes d_0+c_0\otimes d_1)=\mathbf (x, y) \begin{bmatrix} c_1\otimes d_0\\  c_0\otimes d_1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Also why is that $R\otimes_R R \cong R$?

Comment: @palio: as for your last question: convince yourself that the map $R \rightarrow R \otimes_R R$, $r \mapsto 1 \otimes r$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: is this an isomorphism of $R-$modules? and is this an isomorphism because of $\otimes_R$ taken over $R$? what about $R\otimes_{\mathbb Z} R$ for example?

Answer (score 3):

As preliminary computation, I suggest you to consider the classical example of Koszul complex $(K,d):=(S(X^{*})\otimes \wedge (X^{*}), d)$, where $X$ is a finite dim. vector space over $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$ and $S(X^{*})$, resp. $\wedge (X^{*})$ denote the symmetric resp. exterior algebra over $X$.

It is helpful because you can consider the symmetric and the exterior algebras as *suitable* algebra of polynomials and the construction is really explicit.

Let us specify that the Koszul complex is negatively graded, i.e.

$K^{-p}:= S(X^{*})\otimes \wedge^{p} (X^{*}) \rightarrow S(X^{*})\otimes \wedge^{p-1} (X^{*}) \rightarrow \dots \rightarrow S(X^{*})\otimes \wedge^{0} (X^{*}) \rightarrow \mathbb K$

in order to have a degree $+1$ differential $d$, which is given (on monomials in $\wedge^{p} (X^{*})$) by

$d(q \otimes (x_1 \wedge\dots\wedge x_p)):=\sum_{i=1}^{p}(-1)^{i-1} q\cdot x_i \otimes
(x_i\wedge\dots \wedge\hat{x}_i\wedge\dots\wedge x_p))$,
where $\hat{\cdot}$ denotes omission and $q\cdot x_i$ is the product in the symmetric algebra of the polynomial $q$ and the monomial $x_i$. The sign $(-1)^{i-1}$ comes from the fact that $x_i$ "surpasses" $x_1\wedge\dots \wedge x_{i-1}$ to reach the polynomial $q$ on the left.

This formula for the differential is exactly the one which appears in the Wiki-article on the Koszul complex you mention in your question.
The reduction to your case is now straightforward.

Comment: Your formulae seem correct to me; one short comment. The unital ring $R$ is an $R$-$R$-bimodule, where the bimodule structure is induced by the associative product in $R$ (check it). Then the tensor product $R\otimes_R R$ is well defined (because the left copy of $R$ in the product is seen as an $R$-right module, while the copy on the right as an $R$-left module) and it is an $R$-$R$-bimodule as well. If we focus only on the left $R$-module strucure on both $R$ and $R\otimes_R R$, then the map in Nils Matthes' comment above is an isomorphism of left $R$-modules (with $\otimes_R$!)

Comment: Do you have a reference for the content of your post? Thanks.

Comment: Some references: Weibel's book on Homological algebra, ,this paper https://archive.org/details/arxiv-1002.2561 and Loday & Vallette's book on Operads

Answer (score 1):

As you were told in the comments $\partial_2:R=R\otimes R\to (R\otimes R)\oplus (R\otimes R)=R^2$, and $$\partial_2(1)=\partial_2(1\otimes 1)=(-1\otimes y,x\otimes 1)=(-y,x).$$

Similarly, $\partial_1:R^2=(R\otimes R)\oplus (R\otimes R)\to R\otimes R=R$, and 
$$\partial_1(1,0)=\partial_1(1\otimes 1,0\otimes 0)=x\otimes 1=x$$
$$\partial_1(0,1)=\partial_1(0\otimes 0,1\otimes 1)=1\otimes y=y.$$