# Tensor Product of Complexes and the definition of the differentials

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, tensor-products

Suppose we have the following complexes,

$$0 \rightarrow R \xrightarrow{x_1} R \rightarrow 0$$
$$0 \rightarrow R \xrightarrow{x_2} R \rightarrow 0$$
$$0 \rightarrow R \xrightarrow{x_3} R \rightarrow 0$$

where $R$ is a ring and $x_i \in R$ for all $i$.

If $K.$ and $L.$ are two complexes, then the $n$th term in the tensor product is defined by $(K \otimes L)_n = \oplus_{p+q=n} K_p \otimes L_q$ and the maps are given by $\partial_n(a \otimes b) = \partial'(a) \otimes b + (-1)^p a \otimes \partial''(b)$, where $\partial'$, $\partial''$ are the differentials of the first and second complexes, respectively. So we get,

$$0 \rightarrow R \otimes R \otimes R \rightarrow (R \otimes R \otimes R) \oplus (R \otimes R \otimes R) \oplus (R \otimes R \otimes R) \rightarrow (R \otimes R \otimes R) \oplus (R \otimes R \otimes R) \oplus (R \otimes R \otimes R) \rightarrow R \otimes R \otimes R \rightarrow 0$$

which is obviously the same as

$$0 \rightarrow R \xrightarrow{\partial_3} R \oplus R \oplus R \xrightarrow{\partial_2} R \oplus R \oplus R \xrightarrow{\partial_1} R \xrightarrow{\partial_0} 0$$

We have $\partial_3(1 \otimes 1 \otimes 1) = (x_1 \otimes 1 \otimes 1) + (1 \otimes x_2 \otimes 1) - (1 \otimes 1 \otimes x_3)$. We can of course write this down as $x_1 + x_2 - x_3$ since we are considering $R \otimes R \otimes R$ as just $R$.

**Question**

$x_1+x_2 - x_3$ is *not* contained in $R \oplus R \oplus R$, right? How is $\partial_3$ well-defined then? At first, I just thought of sending the coefficient of $x_1$ to the first summand, that of $x_2$ to the second summand, and so on.

But then I realized that $\partial_2$ is defined by sending $(a,b,c) \in R^3$ to $(\partial_2(a), \partial_2(b), \partial_2(c))$, right?

So how are these maps defined?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @user26857 Yes $R = A$...sorry. I did consider the tensor product of the three complexes so I'm not sure what you mean. I didn't explicitly write down those steps in my question but I can if you want me to. I was actually reading about the Koszul complex in Matsumura (p.127) (and that's actually what made me ask this question) and also searched online to read more about the tensor product of complexes...but I wasn't able to find anything that answers my specific question that I asked above. I can elaborate if anything is unclear in my question.

Comment: It seems to me that you are on a wrong way. For keeping track of the differentials you should proceed step by step, that is, find the Koszul complex for two elements (see [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1305415/121097)) and then tensor the obtained complex by the third. For instance, I've got $\partial_3(1)=(x_3,-x_2,x_1)$ or $(-x_2,x_1,x_3)$ it depends on how you want to consider $R^3=R\oplus R^2$ or $R^2\oplus R$. (On page 8 of [this file](http://www.ndsu.edu/pubweb/~ssatherw/sp14/790/koszul120611.pdf) you get the Koszul complex and its differentials for three elements.)

Comment: @user26857 Thanks I see how it works now :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Explicit example of Koszul complex](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/258590/explicit-example-of-koszul-complex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\require{cancel}$Let me deal with the case of the tensor product of two complexes (I hope after that the case of three complexes should be easy). So let the first complex be $C = (0 \to R_1 \xrightarrow{x_1} R_0 \to 0)$, and the second one $C' = (0 \to R'_1 \xrightarrow{x_2} R'_0 \to 0)$; of course $R_0 = R_1 = R'_0 = R'_1 = R$, but this notation change will be helpful for what follows.

We want to compute $C \otimes C'$; it is equal to:
$$0 \to R_1 \otimes R'_1 \xrightarrow{d_2} (R_1 \otimes R'_0) \oplus (R_0 \otimes R'_1) \xrightarrow{d_1} R_0 \otimes R'_0 \to 0.$$

The differentials are computed as follows:
$$d_2(\underbrace{a \otimes b}_{\in R_1 \otimes R'_1}) = \underbrace{x_1 a \otimes b}_{\in R_0 \otimes R'_1} - \underbrace{a \otimes x_2 b}_{\in R_1 \otimes R'_0}$$
$$d_1(\underbrace{a \otimes b}_{\in R_1 \otimes R'_0}) = \underbrace{x_1 a \otimes b}_{\in R_0 \otimes R'_0} - a \otimes \cancel{d_0 b}$$
$$d_1(\underbrace{a \otimes b}_{\in R_0 \otimes R'_1}) = \underbrace{a \otimes x_2 b}_{\in R_0 \otimes R'_0} + \cancel{d_0 a} \otimes b$$

So now we can make all the identifications $R_0 = R_1 = R'_0 = R'_1 = R$ and use $R \otimes R = R$. We thus get a complex:
$$C \otimes C' = (0 \to R \xrightarrow{d_2} R^2 \xrightarrow{d_1} R \to 0),$$
where:
$$d_2(a) = (-x_2 a, x_1 a), \qquad d_1(a,b) = x_1 a + x_2 b.$$

Comment: [Linked](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1305415/121097) into the comments.