# What is Ext in the case of polynomial ring?

Tags: homological-algebra, derived-functors

Let $R=k[x_1,x_2]$ where $k$ is a field and consider the $R$-module $M=R/(x_1,x_2) \cong k$. What is $\text{Ext}^n_R(M,M)$?

I am also wondering if the result can be generalized to find $\text{Ext}^n_R(M,M)$ if $R=k[x_1,...,x_n]$ and $M=R/(x_1,...,x_n)$?

Comment: $k$ has a rather simple free resolution as a $k[x,y]$-module (the Koszul complex), have you tried to compute the Ext group using it? Can you compute it when $R = k[x]$?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Thanks for your comment. I found the resolution $0 \to R \to R^2 \to R \to R/(x_1,x_2) \to 0$. But I am having difficulties to find this resolution for the case in several variables. How can I find it?

Answer (score 6):

When $R = k[x,y]$ and $I = (x,y)$, there's a simple free resolution of $R/I = k$ as a $R$-module, given by the Koszul complex:
$$0 \to R \xrightarrow{d_2} R^2 \xrightarrow{d_1} R \to k \to 0,$$
where $d_2(P) = (xP,yP)$ and $d_1(P,Q) = -yP + xQ$. You can then use it to compute the Ext functor, which is the cohomology of the following cochain complex:
$$0 \gets \hom_R(R,k) \xleftarrow{d^2} \hom_R(R^2,k) \xleftarrow{d^1} \hom_R(R,k) \gets 0,$$
where $d^1(f)(P,Q) = f(-yP+xQ)$ and $d^2(g)(P) = g(xP,yP)$. One can use the isomorphisms
$$\hom_R(R,k) \cong k, \quad f \mapsto f(1) \\
\hom_R(R^2,k) \cong k^2, \quad f \mapsto (f(1,0), f(0,1))$$
to simplify the complex. It becomes
$0 \gets k \xleftarrow{d^2} k^2 \xleftarrow{d^1} k \gets 0$
and both differentials are zero. It follows that:
$$\operatorname{Ext}^n_{k[x,y]}(k,k) = \begin{cases}
k & n = 0 \\
k^2 & n = 1 \\
k & n = 2 \\
0 & n \ge 3
\end{cases}.$$

When you have more variables, there is still a Koszul complex. In general, for an element $z \in R$, denote the Koszul chain complex $K_z = (0 \to R \xrightarrow{z \cdot} R \to 0)$. Then when $R = k[x_1, \dots, x_n]$, you can consider the tensor product of the chain complexes $$K_{x_1} \otimes \dots \otimes K_{x_n},$$
and this gives a free resolution of $k$ as a $R$-module. [You can find an example of computation here (for the case $n=2$)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1304661/10014), in higher dimensions it's not much more difficult. Beware of the signs involved in the definition of the tensor product! This lets you compute $\operatorname{Ext}^n_R(k,k)$ as above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you explain what you mean by "both differentials are zero"?

Comment: @WeylAlg I mean $d^1 = d^2 = 0$.

Comment: How do you know $d_2 = d_1 = 0$?

Comment: @octoberbear Take $\lambda \in k$, let's compute $d^1(\lambda)$. Under the isomorphism $k = \hom_R(R,k)$, $\lambda$ corresponds to $f_\lambda : R \to k$ given by $f_\lambda(P) = \lambda \cdot P(0,0)$ (because we are viewing $k$ as $R/I$). Then we want to compute $d^1 f_\lambda \in \hom_R(R^2,k)$. By definition $$(d^1 f_\lambda)(P,Q) = f_\lambda(d_1(P,Q)) = f_\lambda(-y P + x Q) = \lambda \cdot (-0 \cdot P(0,0) + 0 \cdot Q(0,0)) = 0$$ and the corresponding element of $k^2 = \hom_R(R^2,k)$ is indeed zero. The same reasoning works for $d^2$, try to write it down.